# Help with this code ( gives a STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION )

Tags: c, network-programming

Below is a code where I want to display the ip address of the address entered by the user but it gives me STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION and I am not understanding the reason for it.

It compiles fine. Here is it

```
#ifndef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#endif

// Link to ws2_32.lib
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct protoent *proto=NULL;
int main(int count, char *strings[])
{   
  int pid;
  struct hostent *host;
  struct sockaddr_in addr;
  if ( count != 3 )
  {
     printf("usage: %s <addr> < Adressflag = 0 for name and 1 for IP  > /n", strings[0] );
     exit(0);
  }
 if ( count == 3 )
 {
     int flag = atoi(strings[2]);
     printf("flag is %d",flag);
     if ( flag == 0)
     {
         pid = getpid();
         proto = getprotobyname("ICMP");
         host = gethostbyname(strings[1]);
         bzero(&addr, sizeof(addr));
         addr.sin_family = host->h_addrtype;
         addr.sin_port = 0;
         addr.sin_addr.s_addr = *(long*)host->h_addr;
         //traceroute(&addr);
         printf("IP of %s is %s",host->h_name , host-> h_addr);
     }
     else
     {

     }
 }
 return 0;
}
```

I am running this in cygwin. Is anyone aware of the error and can anyone tell what am I doing wrong ??

Comment: please chose a more informative title for your question.

Comment: @Tomalak How to run it from cygwin ?

Comment: @user506710: Read your toolchain's documentation.

Comment: I would be really grateful if somebody can run this and tell me whether it's running fine at their end because then it would probably be a cygwin error in my desktop....Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really need the * on the front?

```
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = *(long*)host->h_addr
```

That means you are de-referencing some random address.

You are also **not** checking host for null.

Comment: If I don't It gives me a warning that assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast.....

Comment: @user506710: That your code is broken without the cast, does NOT mean that you should add the cast. The cast makes your code _more_ broken, but hides the issue at compile-time.

Comment: try removing all the addr code for now until you get the main bit working. What I mean is find the line that isn't working and fix that.

Comment: @Sasquiha So I removed the address part but it does'nt really help as the error still remains.... Could it be because of cygwin also ?

Comment: @user506710 have you check host for being null?

Answer (score 0):

```
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = *(long*)host->h_addr
```

You can't just cast a `char*` to `long*` to get a number from a string, and you probably shouldn't be dereferencing, either.